# SQL no aloja datos

Tags: php

Para el siguiente problema tengo como objeto de practica enviar un formulario a MySQL; mi codigo, que es por el metodo PDO, no marca errores. Entonces cuando lleno los campos, al correr el codigo, la maquina me dice que la insercion de datos fue correcta pero, al fijarme en la base de datos, esta no aloja nada, por mas que actulice. Repito el procedimiento con diferentes datos pero es lo mismo. Entonces mi pregunta es: ¿Que podria estar fallando?

Esta es la conexion al servidor.

```
<?php 
$PDO = new PDO( 
'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_mensajes;charset=UTF8','root','' );
try { 
echo "mensaje enviado";
$sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios( nombre, clave, mensaje) VALUES ( 
:nombre, :clave, :mensaje)");
$sql->bindParam(':nombre',$_POST['nombre']);
$sql->bindParam(':clave',$_POST['clave']);
$sql->bindParam(':mensaje',$_POST['mensaje']);
$sql->execute();

 }catch(PDOexception $e) {
 echo "mensaje no enviado:".$e ->GetMessaje();
 }
 ?>
```

Este es el formulario.

```
<form method="POST" action="insertar.php">
    <h1>Envio de mensaje</h1>
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" required="" placeholder="escribe tu nombre"><br><br>
    <label>Clave:</label>
    <input type="password" required=""  placeholder="escribe tu clave"><br><br>
    <label>Mensaje:</label>
    <textarea  required="" placeholder="escribe tu mensaje"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: tus inpus deberían tener el nombre que atrapas en el $_POST pues dices recibir $_POST['nombre'] pero tu input no tiene ese name, colocaselo a cada uno y nos dices

Comment: Sigue siendo lo mismo; actualizo la tabla y sigue vacia.

Comment: por favor confirmanos que los datos de conexión son correctos, además hazle un `var_dump($sql);` dale editar a tu pregunta y añade lo que te devolvió

Comment: Tu código tiene más cosas extrañas: debes escribir `PDOException`,  respetando las mayúsculas/minúsculas, debes escribir `$e->getMessage`  pues **no existe un método `GetMessaje`** para las Excepciones. Para saber si realmente se insertaron filas debes poner esto después del `execute`: **`echo "Se insertaron: ".$sql->rowCount()." filas";`** También, prueba si los datos se están recibiendo: `echo $_POST['nombre']."-".$_POST['clave']."-".$_POST['mensaje'];`

Comment: Compañeros, el problema es que estoy aprendiendo a programar de manera autodidacta. He ahi los errores que cometo inocentemente, como todo principiante, pero es solo mientras aprendo, ¿o no? Gracias al cielo que supe de esta pagina o me iba a explotar la cabeza del estres, porque no quiero renunciar. Entonces, les agradezco mucho sus recomendaciones y soluciones a mis codigos. Ya saben que existo para que no se sorprendan con una de mis otras dudas. Luego estare editando el problema otra vez. Muchas gracias, de verdad.

Comment: Recuerda como funciona el sitio por favor. Revisa [ask] y tambien vuelve a hacer el [tour]. Bienvenido

Answer (score 3):

Aparte de lo que dicen los compañeros, hay más errores de escritura y de lógica en tu código. Los indico en orden de aparición:

- Las variables recibidas en el POST se deben controlar: propongo el uso de *operadores tenarios* para ello.
- De entrada imprimes un mensaje de éxito en el código antes de ejecutar: propongo una evaluación real de las filas insertadas usando `rowCount`, pues es la única forma de saber si la consulta insertó filas.
- Tenías mal escrito el nombre de la excepción: es `PDOException`
- Tenías mal escrito el método que obtiene el mensaje de error: es `getMessage`

El código tiene más mejoras: a) Informa adecuadamente y realmente de lo que ocurra; b) Usa las variables creadas en la evaluación ternaria para la inserción; c) Crea la instancia PDO cuando se está seguro de que hay datos válidos para insertar ... en fin, yo llamo a esto *programación controlada* (no escribas código mudo en el que hay eventualidades no cubiertas)  y *programación lógica* no crees objetos antes de saber si realmente necesitarás usarlos.

Este sería el código corregido. Espero sea de utilidad.

```
<?php
    $nombre= (empty($_POST['nombre']))  ? NULL : $_POST['nombre'];
    $clave=  (empty($_POST['clave']))   ? NULL : $_POST['clave'];
    $mensaje=(empty($_POST['mensaje'])) ? NULL : $_POST['mensaje'];

    if ($nombre && $clave && $mensaje) {
        $PDO = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_mensajes;charset=UTF8','root','' );
        try { 
                $sql=$PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios( nombre, clave, mensaje) VALUES (:nombre, :clave, :mensaje)");
                $sql->bindParam(':nombre',$nombre);
                $sql->bindParam(':clave',$clave);
                $sql->bindParam(':mensaje',$mensaje);
                $sql->execute();
                $msg="Se insertaron: ".$sql->rowCount()." filas";

         }catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo "mensaje no enviado:".$e ->getMessage();
         }

    }else{

        $msg="No hay datos en las variables del POST";
    }
    echo $msg;   
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas agregarle un name a los input para que el formulario los mande en tu php los reciba:

```
<form method="POST" action="insertar.php">
    <h1>Envio de mensaje</h1>
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" required="" placeholder="escribe tu nombre"><br><br>
    <label>Clave:</label>
    <input type="password" name="clave" required=""  placeholder="escribe tu clave"><br><br>
    <label>Mensaje:</label>
    <textarea  required="" name="mensaje" placeholder="escribe tu mensaje"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
    </form>
```

Comment: Ya corregi, pero la tabla aun no recibe nada. Es estresante.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías tener el atributo `name` en cada uno de tus inputs para que al momento de que los mandas por `$_POST` los interprete

**Es decir si en tu HTML haces**

```
<input type="text" name="nombre" /> <!--y yo pongo alfredo-->
```

**En el backend cuando haga**

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
```

> El valor recibido será alfredo

```
<form method="POST" action="insertar.php">
    <h1>Envio de mensaje</h1>
    <label>Nombre:</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" required="" placeholder="escribe tu nombre"><br><br>
    <label>Clave:</label>
    <input type="password" name="clave" required=""  placeholder="escribe tu clave"><br><br>
    <label>Mensaje:</label>
    <textarea name="mensaje" required="" placeholder="escribe tu mensaje"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
    </form>
```